# Forcing non-secure page to redirect to secure page with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Sorry I don't have code, but I didn't see the point in pasting something that's not even right.

I want to use htaccess so that the following url combos redirect:

```
http:// www.mysite.com 
http:// mysite.com
https:// www.mysite.com
```

All should redirect user to

```
https:// mysite.com
```

Appreciate guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force https and non-www, you can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```